# how to change the position of textinput in python/turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, textinput, python-turtle

```
#welcome Player 1 and print the players name

player1 = sc.textinput("Name of Player X", "Whats your name? ")
movingTurtle.penup()
movingTurtle.goto(-275, 240)
movingTurtle.pendown()
sc.wel_Player1 = movingTurtle.write("Welcome Player X: "+player1, 
font=FONT2)
```

this code works fine , a little "message-box" pop´s up and asks the 1st player for his name -- the problem is that i cant change the position of that TEXTINPUT-BOX -- i dont even know, if this is possible

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same question and I've looked everywhere for an answer!

Unfortunately, from what I've found, there **doesn't** seem to be any way to modify the position or general look of a textinput box.

Have a look at ->     [This similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175289/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-location-of-a-text-box-in-turtle-it-always-shows-u)

*This might be what you're looking for.*

If anyone *can* actually propose a different way, that would be much appreciated however *my conclusion is that a textinput dialog box **cannot** be modified sadly.*

What I've done is commit to the look by adding a black *backdrop-type* box behind it and making it a bit more obvious and professional that way.

```
#the black backdrop
useroptionboxback = turtle.Turtle()
useroptionboxback.speed(0)
useroptionboxback.shapesize(stretch_wid=6.8,stretch_len=10)
useroptionboxback.shape('square')
useroptionboxback.color('black')
useroptionboxback.penup()
useroptionboxback.goto(-215,255)
useroptionboxback.direction = 'stop'

#the tetinput box
title1 = 'Menu'
prompt1 = 'Please type a number.'
useroptionbox = turtle.textinput(title1, prompt1)
wn.update()
```

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Hg7.png)
I would recommend doing something like this if you find what the guy on the link is saying too confusing.